# How to get type of undefined object property typed in interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to convert undefinedable object property which is defined in a interface.

```
interface activity {

     activityId:number | undefined
}

var obj:activity ={activityId:undefined};

console.log( typeof obj.activityId) ;

//output: "undefined"
Expected behaviour : "number"
```

Comment: TypeScript types are erased at compile time, so they can't appear in your program's runtime code. You could initialize `obj.activityId` with `0` or `NaN` if you want to see `"number"` for `typeof obj.activityId`.

Answer (score 1):

This works as inteded, as specified in you interface `activityId` can be `number` **or** `undefined`.

In your case you declared it as `undefined` and when you run the `typeof`, `activityId` is actually undefined.
When you run:

```
const obj: activity = { activityId: 0 };
console.log(typeof obj.activityId) ;
```

it will show `number` in the console.

`typeof` is pure javascript and it can not show all possible types.

Comment: Do you know another way to get the type of object property?

Comment: At runtime the type is `undefined` and I dont know a way to change that in your case. If your activity ids are allways positive and you need the number type you could initialize the activityId with `-1`. That way you know know whitch activicty has a default id and the type of number.

Comment: hi Norbert, the activityId variable coming from the api, I can't change the variable bro...